# Sending Message Using Twilio-C#

Tags: c#, twilio

Hy... I'm learning twilio rightnow, and I have seen a post here http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Send-SMS-Using-Twilio-ASPNet

I have made my own code because in above site "sendSMSMessage" is deprecated now, but Here is my code :

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Twilio;
namespace SMSUsingTwilio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACMYSID"; 
            String AUTH_TOKEN = "40MYAUTHTOKEN";

            TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

            Message Response = client.SendMessage("(732)305-8856", "+6285220446195", "Hellow Hyosoka Poipo :D");
            

            Console.WriteLine(Response.Status);
            Console.WriteLine(Response.AccountSid);
            
            Console.WriteLine("SMS Berhasil di kirim");
            Console.ReadLine();    
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't any sms message to my phone number and even I don't get any response in my C# project:
[image]

So what's wrong here...?? Please help..Thank you so much...:)

Comment: might it be the phone number format? in https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages they use +17323058856

Comment: Ooowh... I have tried that format... It was same result... :)

Comment: You might wanna remove your account sid and auth token. :P

Comment: On your reference link the 1st parameter of SendSMSMessage is "(502) 276-8990". Notice there is a space between ')' and '2'. Not sure if that is the cause but it's worth a try.

Comment: Same result... Stilll empty... :'(

Comment: Is your account free trial?

Comment: iyyaaps... it's free.... Buut I finally find the answer... fiuuh...

Comment: Yeah with free account you need to do a bit more stuffs to get it working :)

Comment: Yap..it seems like that.... >.<

Answer (score 3):

After seeing mr.David answer, I realized that my phone number was not yet verified. So go to this link for verifying my number:

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified

After that, I run my project agian and here is the result :
[image]

Yeeeiii...Thanks so much for your comments and answer... I really appreciate it... :)

Answer (score 1):

The above looks fine:

```
var message = client.SendMessage("(732)305-8856", "+6285220446195", "Hellow Hyosoka Poipo :D");
```

**Example:**

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    string AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
    string AuthToken = "[AuthToken]"; 
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken); 

    var message = twilio.SendMessage("(732)305-8856", "+6285220446195", "Hellow Hyosoka Poipo :D"); 
    ); 
    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid); 
 }
```

Check this out:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

I don't recognise your phone numbers, if the above example does not work it will be an issue with your account or the number format.

Comment: Thank you mr.David, I find a clue from your answer btw... ehehe... Yeaah...my code is right but my phone number is not verify yet... :v
So I go to verified page...aand...I finally got my message response... I will post the detail step later... :)
Thank you in advance Mr. David... :)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your detailed answer here. Would you be interested in receiving a t-shirt from us? Email mspeir@twilio.com for details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to install a Twillio NuGet package from Numget Manager
Otherwise, 
You can write code `Install-Package Twilio` 
in Package manager console.

- You need to create Twillo account from https://www.twilio.com
- Now you get AccountId, AuthToken etc
- Then you will need to implement the following code in your project:

> ```
> public async Task<string> SendTwilioSMS(string phoneNumber, string SMS)
> {
>             string returnMessage = string.Empty;
>             string bodySMS = SMS;
>             var twilioAccountSid = "AC754fec249d22766caf0ae4e58a158271";
>             var twilioAuthToken = "cfecd5ff4d751677fc2e2875e3739b55";
>             var twilioMessagingServiceSid = "MGd57fcc863cb37dcff135aca43b4bb7d1";
>             var twilioPhoneNumber = "+919714285344";
>
>             bodySMS = SMS;
>             TwilioClient.Init(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);
>             try
>             {
>                 MessageResource twillioResult = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
>                    to: new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber),
>                    from: new PhoneNumber(twilioPhoneNumber),
>                    body: bodySMS,
>                    messagingServiceSid: twilioMessagingServiceSid
>                    );
>                 returnMessage = "Message sent";
>             }
>             catch (Exception err)
>             {
>                 returnMessage = err.Message;
>             }
>             return returnMessage;
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The value should be brought from appsettings file if using .Net Core.

```cs
public async Task SendSMS()
{
    var sid = "0845-373A-90fy-5790";
    var authToken = "5a983-498f94-2849o8934-28455s9";
    try
    {
        TwilioClient.Init(sid , authToken );
    
        var message = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
            body: "Hi",
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+12564598"),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("9467345243"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log Exception
    }
}
```